# Directive with nested elements in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs and I am trying to write a directive with nested elements.

```
<mydir-table>
    <mydir-columns>
        <mydir-column>
            <title>Employee Name</title>
            <data-field-name>ename</data-field-name>
        <mydir-table>
    <mydir-columns>
<mydir-column>
```

I have a JSON something similar to this:

```
{
    rows: [
        {
            name: "Emp1"
        },
        {
            name: "Emp2"
        }
    ]
}
```

and expected output is:

```
<table>
    <th>
        Employee Name
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Emp 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Emp 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone please provide some thoughts on how this can be implemented?

Comment: What is the specific problem you are encountering? What have you tried? Right now, your question is: "here's some problem - solve it for me".

Comment: There are a lot of existing table modules out there. You don't have to invent your own. If you really want to build your own table directive, have a look how they solved problems. I like http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

Comment: What have you done till now? Anything that you tried and failed, or you looked at but couldn't understand? If we know them we will help you better.